# which ORM is used with spring boot + mongodb

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot

am working with spring boot + mongodb project and i've been searching lately to know which orm am using but am still confused, i didn't find any clear information, some says hibernate and other says it's Spring Data, even though i know that hibernate works just with MySQL bases but for the NoSQL bases i didn't find any clear information about which ORM am using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **Spring data mongodb**.

It's the easiest one to integrate Springboot with mongo.

```
api("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb")
```

Comment: Oh okay ! thanks a lot i appreciate your help